# Music files doubled after copied from computer

Tags: 8.0, music, nokia-lumia-820

When I copied some music files from my computer to my phone via Explorer, they appeared twice on my `Music+Videos`, as if there were two of them. Both files can be played, and from the storage check I can tell that there is only one copy in fact.
How can I solve this problem?

I'm using Music+Videos app, and it's my only app to play music.

Comment: When you copied them via Explorer, did you copy the music to the phone memory or SD card?

Comment: @NeilTurner, SD card.

Comment: It should not happen like that. If you have copied it to the SD Card then it should just show it once. It must be a small bug, You can try syncing again or deleting all the files and copying them all over again.

Comment: @IcyFlame, I tried to delete them all and copy again, now there are three copies of each file...

Comment: oh! Well then it seems like the deleted files are not being removed from the index! Great! The immediate thing comes to my mind is that you should reset the phone! Or since you have an SD card, You could back it up and then format it..! If that does not work, go for the hard reset..! You see whenever there is a problem I can' solve by Googling my way around or by Changing settings, I just reset the phone and generally(read 100%) the problem is solved and I get a faster device! its unfortunate, But that is how Windows Phone is designed!!

Comment: Its simple delete unwanted mp3 player,Lumia phone have music+videos apps and nokia music apps those apps only use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this problem. Maybe it will multiply again. The solution is very simple. First you back up all the songs. Then you should clear the thumbnail cache of Music. This will be hidden in Music folder of Phone memory. After you did this you can use Windows Phone's desktop app to sync the music. If you want to copy via Explorer you should rearrange your music folder structure as Music Folder > Artist Folder > Album Folder > Songs.