# Songs appearing multiple times

Tags: music, mediaplayer

When I look at the song list, many songs appear multiple times (more specifically, it seems like they appear exactly 14 times). I have checked the SD card on my computer to see if I had any duplicates, and I did, but certainly not so many and not of so many songs.

Furthermore, when I go into the memory settings, it shows my SD space usage as 12,22 GB, which is likely correct, but when I go into the details, it says that music and videos take up 52,26 GB of space, which is baffling considering the card in question only has 16 GB to begin with.

Besides making the song list very tedious to browse, I suspect it contributes to the significant slowdowns I experience whenever I start the music playing.

I've found a [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/multiple-duplicatetriplicate-music-files-on/1176332d-35cd-4cb8-beb4-877f49f8fae7) about a similarly related, but apparently much less severe problem, but even there there are no real solutions.

Is it a known problem? Any hints or solutions?

Comment: Posting as comment because my memory of this answer is incomplete - but I believe that duplicates may sometimes appear due to "Xbox Live Synchronization" - some sort of half-baked attempt to synchronize your music automatically. There should be a setting to turn it off. If I'm wrong, perhaps it only affects playlists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Music files doubled after copied from computer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/music-files-doubled-after-copied-from-computer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Back up all the songs.
2. Clear the thumbnail cache of Music. (Music folder of Phone memory).
3. Use Windows Phone's desktop app to sync the music.
4. If you want to copy via Explorer you should rearrange your music
   folder structure as Music Folder > Artist Folder > Album Folder >
   Songs.

Comment: How do I do the second step?

Comment: Connect to PC and enable show hidden files in folder options (If you're using Windows). Open your phone as in Explorer (as Portable device) and delete all files in Music folder (not Folder itself) of Phone Memory. *Windows Phone* > *Phone Memory* > *Music*

Comment: I did that (and formatted the SD card) and there was some progress: songs now only appear twice, not fourteen times... Maybe copying through the app and not explorer would prevent that, but I think I'm gonna give up now, especially since the slowdowns seem to have subsided almost completely, so the biggest problem is gone. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you did the steps strictly as I said, this problem will be resolved.

Comment: deleting is taking horribly long.

Comment: @Ramit I didn't mentioned about deleting here. Step 4 is unnecessary for phones with Windowsphone 8.1 I hope.

Comment: so, when we say 'clear the thumbnail,' r we not saying delete it?

Comment: `Clear the thumbnail cache` implies that delete all the thumbnail files (not the music files, these are images, playlists or other kinds) inside the phone's music folder.